# How to find the min, where TSQL groups by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have found the first transaction (min), but when I add the column 'Winners', I get a row for their first win and a row for their first loss. I need only the first row, including whether they won or lost. I have tried aggregating the winners column to no avail. I would prefer not to sub-query if possible. Thanks in advance for checking this out.

```
SELECT 
MIN(dbo.ADT.Time) AS FirstShowWager, 
dbo.AD.Account,  dbo.AD.FirstName, 
dbo.AD.LastName, dbo.ADW.Winners  

FROM     
dbo.BLAH
WHERE       
(dbo.ADT.RunDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-04-12
00:00:00', 102)) AND (dbo.ADW.Pool = N'shw') 

GROUP BY
dbo.AD.Account, 
dbo.AD.FirstName,
dbo.AD.LastName,
dbo.AD.RunDate, 
dbo.ADW.Winners 

ORDER BY 
dbo.AD.Account
```

Comment: If adding Winners messes you up, why not simply take it out?

Comment: I wish i could! I need to know whether they won or lost on their first transaction though :/

Comment: What kinda column is winners?

Comment: can you move winners to your where i.e. `where dbo.adw.Winners = something`?

Comment: Winners is an integer column. Null for losing, a number for winning.

Comment: Winners I believe needs to be aggregated as a case statement, I just don't understand how yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sorted.* 
from 
(
    SELECT dbo.ADT.Time AS FirstShowWager, 
           dbo.AD.Account,  dbo.AD.FirstName, 
           dbo.AD.LastName, dbo.ADW.Winners,  
           ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (partition by dbo.AD.Account, 
                                             dbo.AD.FirstName,
                                             dbo.AD.LastName,
                                             dbo.AD.RunDate
                                    order by dbo.ADT.Time) as rowNum
      FROM dbo.AD
     WHERE dbo.ADT.RunDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-04-1200:00:00', 102) 
       AND dbo.ADW.Pool = N'shw'
) as sorted 
where rowNum = 1
```

[ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: I don't know why you are getting a order by error.  But I had an error on the rowNum =

Comment: I had an additional order by in the query by mistake. I feel this is the right path to take, but it is not selecting their first record every time, occasionally (about every 10 records) selects their second transaction

Comment: Try is again. I made a change.

Comment: Awesome this works perfectly, Thank you and I learned some new SQL today!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't care about the value of winners column, by grouping on winners you'd get multiple rows, one for null and others for non-null values. If you don't care about the amount they've won but just simply if they've won or lost, you can do something like this,

```
SELECT 
MIN(dbo.ADT.Time) AS FirstShowWager, 
dbo.AD.Account,  dbo.AD.FirstName, 
dbo.AD.LastName, CASE WHEN dbo.ADW.Winners IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

FROM     
dbo.BLAH
WHERE       
(dbo.ADT.RunDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-04-12
00:00:00', 102)) AND (dbo.ADW.Pool = N'shw') 

GROUP BY
dbo.AD.Account, 
dbo.AD.FirstName,
dbo.AD.LastName,
dbo.AD.RunDate, 
dbo.ADW.Winners 

ORDER BY 
dbo.AD.Account
```

Comment: This is what I originally thought would work, but the following error appears "Winners is invalid in the select list, it needs to be contained in either an aggregate function or group by clause."

Comment: Then you can go MAX(CASE WHEN dbo.ADW.Winners IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) in the select list, but then you'll get 1 row, 0 or 1.

Comment: and by leaving Winners in the group by clause, we get their first win and their first loss.

Comment: If you don't care whether they lost or won, why do you need the Winners column in the select or group by?

Comment: I do care if they won or lost. I need to know whether they won or lost on their first wager only. Does MAX select 1 over 0? or does it select the first wager?

Comment: Sounds like you need an inner join, between this query and inner join dbo.ADT ON dbo.ADT = FirstShowManager and select the winners from the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Add this case statement instead of winners column in the select statement and group by

```
 Case ( winners is NULL then 'Lose' else 'Win' end )
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done with a derived table selecting the record you want then joining back to the orginal table on all the group by fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the MIN in an inner query and then join it to the ADW table on by the ID to get if they are a winner.

```
SELECT b.*, ADW.winner 
FROM dbo.ADW ADW INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(ADT.RunTime) AS FirstShowWager, 
                             AD.Account,  AD.FirstName, 
                             AD.Lastnamne, AD.ADID
                             FROM dbo.AD AD INNER JOIN dbo.ADT ADT AD.adid = ADT.ADID 
                             GROUP BY AD.Account, AD.Firstname, AD.Lastnamne, AD.ADID) b
    ON ADW.ADID = b.ADID
```

Assumptions:  There is a foreign key between
From the ADT to the AD table.
From the ADW to the AD table.